# (XPage/JS svr-side)How to calculate the year, month and day two weeks from today?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

```
var TODAY_TEMP = @Text(@Year(@Today()))+@Right("0"+@Text(@Month(@Today())),2)+@Right("0"+@Text(@Day(@Today())),2);
```

I need to calculate two weeks from today, I already get today, but I don't know how to get the date of after two weeks.

So sorry... I'm not familiar with how to write programs on the javascript server-side...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [@Adjust function](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/reference/r_wpdr_atfunctions_adjust_r.html). Example:

```
@Adjust(@Today(), null, null, 14, null, null, null);
```